# MinLength Validator treats 0 as zero length

Tags: validation, angular6

I have below code to validation one field, this field keeps numbers value
   When the value is 0,
   then validation fails, because minLength treats 0 as 0 length

Scenario: I have discount field which is mandatory from HTML, and minLength 1 
   from angular.

It should accept 0, but in this case form in invalid

```
 discount: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.maxLength(5),
        Validators.minLength(1),
  ])),
```

I dont wan't to use Validators.required as per my requirement only minLength I need to use, which will come from data base(As of now I just hard coded)

```
  discount: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
        Validators.maxLength(5),

  ])),
```

Please Help